# Web Service Code refactoring

Tags: java, web-services, refactoring

Its more of a good practice question. Currently our projects have tons of code in a single web service impl class. All the code is pretty much written in this main class.

whenever we make schema/wsdl changes, I have to take back up of the exist class and then regenerate the impl class form wsdl. then copy the non changed code into it piece by piece.

I want to change the approach by adding other helper/general classes into the mix and majority of the code would be in this non generated classes. The impl class will have minimal code that will call these other classes. This way the 'back up and cut paste job after regeneration is minimal.

What is the common practice? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I hate SOAP, but I think the common practice is to derive the WSDL from the code, rather than generating the code from the WSDL. That avoids the pain of having to regenerate the code.

Comment: And how do you generate it from the code?

Comment: I think we are talking about two different approaches. [Read Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890438/what-is-the-difference-between-a-top-down-web-service-and-a-bottom-up-web-servic) Both are common depending upon your situation.