# WebServices and WebSphere - simple - deployed 2 different ways, received 2 different results

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, websphere

**Intro:**  following a tutorial for EE project setup, currently am able to generate an XHTML with JSF2.0, utilize some ManagedBeans, have some DataAccess Objects and Service implementations.

**Current Topic:**  tutorial has a SOAP JAX-WS section for creating a simple WebService

**Issue:**

1. Deploying via Eclipse Keplar's servers tab to my WAS 8.5 server
   results in 404|fileNotFound exception in browser, no console errors.
   (Seems the web service isn't working.)

This link:
http://localhost:9080/ListManagerWebServices/UserSoapService?wsdl

Provides this result:

> Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found:
>   /UserSoapService

1. Deploying via WAS's admin console under New Application and
   triggering the "Deploy WebServices" does work

This link:
http://localhost:9080/ListManagerWebServices/UserSoapService?wsdl

Provides this results:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

3. Why do the web services not fire when I deploy in the servers tab,
   but do when I explicitly enable it from the admin console?
4. How can I enable the web services to fire after the deployment to
   the server from the servers tab?

***UserSoapService.java***

```
package com.pluralsight.listmanager.web.service.soap;

import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.pluralsite.listmanager.model.ListItem;
import org.pluralsite.listmanager.model.User;
import org.pluralsite.listmanager.service.UserService;
import org.pluralsite.listmanager.service.impl.UserServiceImpl;

@WebService(serviceName="UserSoapService")
public class UserSoapService {


    private final UserService userService;


    public UserSoapService() {
        this.userService = new UserServiceImpl();
    }


    @WebMethod
    public Long getUserId(@WebParam(name="username") String username) {
        User user = userService.authenticateUser(username);

        if (user != null) {
            return user.getId();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @WebMethod 
    public List<ListItem> getUserListItems(@WebParam(name="userId") Long userId) {
        return userService.getListItems(userId);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial you're following? Did you already generate the WSDL or are you generating the WSDL during deployment?

Comment: The tutorial is on a paid site, unfortunately for this.  Perhaps, some explanation into the creation of things could help:

The working EAR, which included a separate WAR,deploy and function, no problem.

I created a new dynamic web project, then in that project, in the Java Resources "src" folder, I created the code you see above - ctrl-shift-o'd the imports, including a binding to my datasource in the binding file, and deployed.  No luck.  Exported the same EAR, now with the webService WAR as well, and installed via the admin console - selected deploy web services - and it worked.

Comment: I'm also unclear on what a WSDL is/does, I don't know if it is deployed or exists, however - within my Project I have the following structure:

 Java Resources  || Services  ||  JavaScript Resources  ||  WebRoot  .  Under **Services** I have 1 listing:  {http://soap.service.web.listmanager.pluralsight.com/}UserSoapService.  Clicking on it takes me to my class, in the code above

Comment: Edit (for WSDL):  This link was useful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890438/what-is-the-difference-between-a-top-down-web-service-and-a-bottom-up-web-servic